# Sources of inspiration for the graphical design of a business intelligence web application

Tags: website-design

I'm looking for sources of inspiration for the graphical design of a web application.

The application is used to display historical information on industrial processes. In the back end there is a time-series database and a data warehouse.

The users of the application will configure pages with various information displays of data, for instance:

- Dashboard-style displays, with selected KPIs, as numbers and visualized
- Visualizations like line and bar plots
- Tables containing numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked on a similar product and found some useful resources:

–
Good theory and examples at http://www.dashboardinsight.com. 
Noah Illinsky is a great authority on data visualisation http://complexdiagrams.com

Nice article: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/11/dashboard-design-101.php

–
Books

http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi

http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920000617

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100162

Answer (score 3):

The best example I've seen recently is Geckoboard. I think they handled the design of BI dashboards very well. http://www.geckoboard.com/

Answer (score 3):

One site that has a lot of screenshots for inspiration would be [Enterprise Dashboards](http://www.enterprise-dashboard.com/). Another (which I'm more familiar with) is [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/tour/opensocial-dashboards.jsp), which is very powerful on customization. You can get almost anything you want on your dashboard and no configuration needed!